# How can I view recently added songs in iTunes grouped by Album like the Songs view does?

Tags: itunes, metadata

I have just added 6 albums worth of downloaded music to my iTunes library. I know that some of the files will not be identified as the same album by iTunes because of different Album Artist metadata, and some of the tracks will be missing track or disc numbers. These problems are easiest to see in the Songs view, where I can see one album split in half, then select all of the offending songs and apply the 'Compilation' flag or correct the missing metadata. However, the only way I can find to filter my view down to just the newly added tracks is using the Recently Added smart playlist, which does not give me a preview of the Songs view's album grouping behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, in the 'music' section, sort by date added, select the six albums worth of songs and create a New Playlist from Selection (Cmd-Shft-N, or right-click on selection). From that playlist, you should have the view you want.